# Relay Node on Cardano

Tags: cardano-node

Hello I have recently set up a relay node. Is there a helpful guide/video i can access to create a wallet and send transactions on the relay node? Thanks in Advance?

---

Thank you for your answers. I shall try these

Answer (score 1):

Here are your options:
Either you create payment keys using the cardano-cli which let's you generate them. Then you create an address from those payment keys and fund it with ADA. Lastly, you can use the cardano-cli to create & submit txs to your node.
https://developers.cardano.org/docs/stake-pool-course/handbook/create-simple-transaction/

Or secondly, you use a light wallet like Nami and connect it to your relay node to submit transactions.
https://forum.cardano.org/t/setting-up-a-custom-node-for-nami-wallet/94333

Comment: is it better to link nami to daedalus node or relay node? Thanks

Comment: doesn't really matter, Daedalus runs the same node software but also comes with a HD wallet and some other components.

Comment: @Cardanofan if you like my response you can mark it as answer! 

Answer (score 0):

do you use CNTOOL or you want to do all this steps by commands, manually?

take a look here,

```
https://developers.cardano.org/docs/integrate-cardano/creating-wallet-faucet
```

i will search for another resource and come back to you